# How can I animate the transition between two modal view controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

**Edited original post for clarity**

I'd like to be able to control the animation between two modal view controllers.  Specifically, I'd like to have the first modal slide down and the second modal fade in behind it.  I just watched the WWDC videos on custom animation transitions and I think that is probably what I want.  My thought is that during the sliding down of modal1, I can fade in modal2 (or an image of modal2) and then just present modal2 normally once the animation is finished.  I'm not sure if this is the *right* way to do it so I'm open to ideas.

This is how I'm dismissing/presenting:

```
 _modal1.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
 [_modal1 setTransitioningDelegate:self];
 [_modal1 dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self presentViewController:_modal2 animated:NO completion:nil];
  }];
```

And here's my delegate method:

```
- (nullable id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed {
    return [CustomDismissAnimation new];
}
```

And my attempt at a transition:

```
@implementation CustomDismissAnimation

- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {

    UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];
    UIView *fromView = [transitionContext viewForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewKey];

    CGRect containerFrame = containerView.frame;
    CGRect fromViewFinalFrame = CGRectMake(0,
                                           containerFrame.size.height,
                                           fromView.frame.size.width,
                                           fromView.frame.size.height);

    UIViewController *test = [UIViewController new];
    [test setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    test = containerFrame;
    [containerView addSubview:test];
    [containerView bringSubviewToFront: test];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext]
                     animations:^{
                         [fromView setFrame:fromViewFinalFrame];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [test removeFromSuperview];
                         [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
                     }];
}

@end
```

My expectation would be that this green test view would appear behind modal1 as it slid down the screen but that doesn't seem to be the case.  It doesn't show up at all.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One simple workaround of that you can't have 2 modal VCs shown , is that create only one modal with 2 views the front is the old and the back is the new (If you want to separate VCs make newVC as a child behind the presented old), and manage the hide/show between them also you can do the animation to the view directly

Comment: I suppose that might work and then I can use the built in view controller transition logic.

Comment: you can animate the view of the newVC or animate it with the transition

Answer (score 1):

So you are saying A presents B, then dismisses B, then presents C, and yet A should not visible while dismissing B and presenting C.

One obvious solution would be to let B present C! When you take C down you could unwind all the way thru B to A in one move.

If you insist upon this hierarchy — that is, if A is present B and then C — B and C cannot occupy the space at the same time, because one view controller (A) cannot present two VCs at once. So *something* is going to appear behind B as it vanishes and then behind C as it appears. However, you are free to say what that is; you could, for example, interpose a "dimming view" in front of A.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. Wouldn’t presenting a dimming view present the same problems as presenting another view controller modally though?

Comment: No because the dimming view would not be presented; it would be just a view.